# A button caption for order submission

Tags: traduction, informatique, commerce

In our app, we use a button caption of “Acheter” when a user submits an order.

However, we've started offering some free items, and some orders are placed without payment.

What would the best translation for “Submit Order”

Are “Soumettre la commande” or “Envoyer l'ordre” too long/formal? We want something common on mobile apps and the web.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider “*Commander*” which means “order” and can be used regardless of whether payment is required.